# How to check if something is countable?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-collection

I have a var: `$a`. I don't know what it is. I want to check if I can count it. Usually, with only array, I can do this:

```
if (is_array($a)) {
    echo count($a);
}
```

But some other things are countable. Let's say a `Illuminate\Support\Collection` is countable with Laravel:

```
if ($a instanceof \Illuminate\Support\Collection) {
    echo count($a);
}
```

But is there something to do both thing in one (and maybe work with some other countable instances). Something like:

```
if (is_countable($a)) {
    echo count($a);
}
```

Does this kind of function exists? Did I miss something?

Comment: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346479/how-to-check-for-arrayness-in-php ? with `$var instanceof Countable`

Comment: @Scuzzy's way is a good start and maybe is worth also trying to see if is traversable: http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

Comment: Good news. It is looking like PHP 7.3 is aiming to have a built in function for this https://wiki.php.net/rfc/is-countable

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### PHP 7.3

According to the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-countable.php), You can use `is_countable` function:

```
if (is_countable($a)) {
    echo count($a);
}
```

Comment: That's for a version of PHP that isn't released yet :D

Comment: PHP 7.3 Alpha 1 is now released. Please also note: PHP 7.3 SHOULD NOT be used in production. Please wait for Production Ready version to save yourself for the hassle.

Comment: We're at 7.4 now, so this answer is now more than acceptable.

Answer (score 29):

For previous PHP versions, you can use this

```
if (is_array($foo) || $foo instanceof Countable) {
    return count($foo);
}
```

or you could also implement a sort of polyfill for that like this

```
if (!function_exists('is_countable')) {

    function is_countable($c) {
        return is_array($c) || $c instanceof Countable;
    }

}
```

---

Note that this polyfill isn't something that I came up with, but rather pulled directly from the RFC for the new function proposal https://wiki.php.net/rfc/is-countable