# Wordpress error: Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: php

The first line is the problem code. I don't know how to change that count to something that can work.

```
if(count($item[2]) > 0){
    if($item[2][0] == 'plane' || $item[2][0] == 'url'){
        if($item[2][0] == 'url'){
            $arr = explode('file/d/',$id);
            $arr1 = explode('/',$arr[1]);
            $id = $arr1[0];
        }
   }
 }
?>
```

Comment: Hi, this is probably caused by the fact that the **$item** variable is not of countable type and thus the **count()** function cannot be used.
What is inside **$item[2]** and what does **$item** hold in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP `7.2`, a Warning was added while trying to count uncountable things. To make it fix change this line:

```
if(count($item[2]) > 0){
```

with this:

```
if(is_array($item[2]) && count($item[2]) > 0){
```

In PHP `7.3` a new function was added `is_countable`, specifically to address the `E_WARNING` issue. If you are using PHP `7.3` so you can change this line:

```
if(count($item[2]) > 0){
```

with this:

```
if(is_countable($item[2]) && count($item[2]) > 0){
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in some cases this `$item[2]` returns `null` or any other non-countable value. Starting from [PHP 7](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration72.incompatible.php), you will not be able to count an object that not implementing countable. So you need to check first if it's an array:

```
if(is_countable($item[2])){ // you can also use is_array($item[2])
    if(count($item[2]) > 0){
        //rest of your code
    }
}
```

Another way (though not preferred) is to pass your object to `ArrayIterator`. That will make it iteratable:

```
$item_2 = new ArrayIterator($item[2]);
if(count($item_2) > 0){
   //rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try code below:

```
if (is_array($item[2]) || $item[2] instanceof Countable || is_object($item[2])) {
    if(count($item[2]) > 0){
        if($item[2][0] == 'plane' || $item[2][0] == 'url'){
            if($item[2][0] == 'url'){
                $arr = explode('file/d/',$id);
                $arr1 = explode('/',$arr[1]);
                $id = $arr1[0];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Check [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42899605/how-to-check-if-something-is-countable)